# assert that struct type is declared with alignas()

Tags: c++, assert, alignas

As the title states, I need some way to assert that a type has been declared with alignas as such:

```
struct alignas(16) MyStruct {
    ...
};
```

It is meant to be used for a template parameter where the template class needs to make sure that the type it is templated on is 16 byte aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [`alignof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) that you can use to make sure the type you get is aligned to the correct size.  You would use it in your function like

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& bar)
{
    static_assert(alignof(T) == 16, "T must have an alignment of 16");
    // rest of function
}
```

If using this in a class you'd have

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
    static_assert(alignof(T) == 16, "T must have an alignment of 16");
    // rest of class
};
```

Comment: You may as well just go straight to `alignof`, save yourself a lot of typing. `alignof` was introduced at the same time as `alignas`.